# How to load only certain columns using fluentnhibernate?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I want to know how can i fill only certain columns while filling the entity object?

i am interested in certain properties of the entity and not all.

but when i use session to fetch the entity it sends query like "select * from Customer" for example.

but i want to do "Select customerName from Customer".

I think it has some thing to do with LazyLoad() but i am not sure how exactly.

Any help will be highly appriciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Ashish

Comment: You don't want LazyLoading, you want Projections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var defs = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(test));
defs.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
    .Add(Projections.Property("FirstColumn"));
```